this code does not work for some devices though it works great on many devices
The code below works great on samsung with android 11 or 12 or other devices with android 10, but it does not work for nokia 6 with android 9 or redmi phone with android 14
I am not getting the logs of media recorder start, set audio format, on some phones,
I am using this code as service in flutter app.
The code work great on many devices, any fixes??
package com.example.app

import android.Manifest
import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException

class AudioRecorderService : Service() {
    private var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    private var isRecording = false
    private var isPaused = false
    private var outputFile: String? = null

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "AudioRecordingChannel"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        private const val REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when (intent?.action) {
            "START" -> {
                outputFile = intent.getStringExtra("outputFile")
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    if (checkPermissions()) {
                        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification())
                        startRecording()
                    } else {
                        Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Permission denied")
                        stopSelf()
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Output file path not provided")
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
            "STOP" -> {
                stopRecording()
                stopForeground(true)
                stopSelf()
            }
            "PAUSE" -> pauseRecording()
            "RESUME" -> resumeRecording()
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this as Activity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }

    private fun startRecording() {
        if (isRecording) return

        try {
            outputFile?.let { path ->
                val file = File(path)
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.parentFile?.mkdirs() // Create parent directories if they don't exist
                    file.createNewFile()
                }

                mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
                    setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                    setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS)
                    setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                    setOutputFile(outputFile)
                    prepare()
                    start()
                }

                Log.i("AudioRecorderService", "Recording started")
                isRecording = true
                isPaused = false
            } ?: run {
                Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Invalid output file path")
                stopSelf()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "IOException occurred: ${e.message}", e)
            stopSelf()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "IllegalStateException occurred: ${e.message}", e)
            stopSelf()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Exception occurred: ${e.message}", e)
        }
    }

    private fun stopRecording() {
        if (!isRecording) return

        try {
            mediaRecorder?.apply {
                stop()
                release()
            }
            Log.i("AudioRecorderService", "Recording stopped")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Exception occurred while stopping recording: ${e.message}", e)
        } finally {
            mediaRecorder = null
            isRecording = false
            isPaused = false
        }
    }

    private fun pauseRecording() {
        if (isRecording && !isPaused && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            try {
                mediaRecorder?.pause()
                isPaused = true
                Log.i("AudioRecorderService", "Recorder paused")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Exception occurred while pausing recording: ${e.message}", e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resumeRecording() {
        if (isRecording && isPaused && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            try {
                mediaRecorder?.resume()
                isPaused = false
                Log.i("AudioRecorderService", "Recorder resumed")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("AudioRecorderService", "Exception occurred while resuming recording: ${e.message}", e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Audio Recording Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            ).apply {
                description = "Channel for audio recording notifications"
            }
            val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Recording Audio")
            .setContentText("Your app is recording audio in the background")
            .build()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        stopRecording()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}


I tried everything but the app gets frozen and does not work on nokia or redmi phone
